# how to calculate the average of numbers and sort them in csv file in python

Tags: python

In this project, you have to write a program that reads the grades of different people from a csv file and performs the following calculations on the grades and saves the resulting values   in a file. In this project, you have to implement 5 different tasks. Do not change the names of the functions in any way and implement all the code you want to do in the same defs.
1- calculate the average of each person and save it along with the name of each person, the output order of the names must be exactly equal to the order of the input file.
2- Save the rates in ascending order along with the name of each person.
3- Save the top three GPAs with each person's name.
4- Save the three low GPAs without each person's name.
5- Calculate and store the average grades.
I did the first task but have problem with others.

```
import csv
# For the average
from statistics import mean 

def calculate_averages(grades, mean):
    with open("address of input csv file") as infile:
        reader=csv.reader(infile)
        with open("address of output csv file" , "w", newline="") as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            for row in reader:
                name = row[0]
                grade_mean = (float(grade) for grade in row [1:])
                writer.writerow([row[0], mean(grade_mean)])




def calculate_sorted_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    


def calculate_three_best(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    


def calculate_three_worst(input_file_name, output_file_name):
        


def calculate_average_of_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
```

for example, the grades csv file contains these:

```
mandana,5,7,3,15
hamid,3,9,4,20,9,1,8,16,0,5,2,4,7,2,1
sina,19,10,19,6,8,14,3
sara,0,5,20,14
soheila,13,2,5,1,3,10,12,4,13,17,7,7
ali,1,9
sarvin,0,16,16,13,19,2,17,8
```

Comment: What have you tried? What tools do you have at your disposal? Can you use pandas? Does all your work have to be row by row?

Comment: Happy to try and help once I know your limitations

Comment: I used pandas but I got this error << Import "pandas" could not be resolved from source>> and I do not know what to do.

Comment: and yes I need all things row by row

Comment: My question is more what tools do you have at your disposal? What have you learned how to use?

I suggested pandas because you can calculate the data and then sort it before you write it to a csv in a much faster format, using column vectorization.

Are you required to do it in any particular way? My initial thought for row by row with sorting would be to store an array with "Rate" and student tuples, and then order them before writing to a csv

Comment: I am free to use anything,

Comment: how do you use them?

Comment: `pandas` is not a part of the standard library, you must download it. you can do `pip install pandas` from a terminal, or if you are using anacanda or something other tool you would, well, want to use that tool however you use it.

Comment: I did that but still have problem

Comment: How are you writing code? is it in vs code? another IDE? if you use conda, you would want to do conda install pandas. Or if pip, pip install pandas.

Then at the top of your file, import pandas so you can access it

Once you do that, you can read in your csv as a table (or, in pandas language, dataframe) by doing df
```
df = pd.from_csv(input_file_name)
```
Once you have done this, you are free to make manipulations. When you have finished, you can do 

df.to_cv(output_file_name) 
which saves it as the file!

Comment: some examples - a way to do this generally with a data of this style:
name | grade
-------|------
 str      |   int

def calculate_sorted_averages(input, output):
    df = pd.from_csv(input)
    # reads csv
    df = df.groupby(by="name", as_index=False).mean()
    # takes the mean (or average) of all averageable data by each "name"
    df = df.sort_values(by="grade", asc=False)
    # sorts the values by the averaged grade column from largest to smallest
    df.to_csv(output)

Comment: I use vs code, I did not understand your explanations. Can you write the code?

Comment: I would look up a pandas tutorial to get comfortable so you can understand the code I wrote. It's three lines and leverages pandas groupby, sort_values, and csv functions. Writing the code for you, however, feels like doing the work rather than teaching you... I also did write the code for your sorted averages above. Once you understand pandas better, take another look

Comment: thank you so much, I'll wait for you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

true answer is:

```
import csv

# # For the average
from statistics import mean 
def calculate_averages(grades, mean):
    with open("address inputfile") as infile:
        reader=csv.reader(infile)
        with open("adress of outputfile" , "w", newline="") as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            for row in reader:
                name = row[0]
                grade_mean = (float(grade) for grade in row [1:])
                writer.writerow([row[0], mean(grade_mean)])




def calculate_sorted_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    avarage_list = []
    with open(input_file_name) as infile:
        reader=csv.reader(infile)
        with open(output_file_name , "w", newline="") as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            for row in reader:
                name = row[0]
                grade_mean = (float(grade) for grade in row [1:])
                avarage_list.append([name, mean(grade_mean)])
            avarage_list.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
            for item in avarage_list:
                writer.writerow([item[0], float(item[1])])


def calculate_three_best(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    avarage_list = []
    with open(input_file_name) as infile:
        reader=csv.reader(infile)
        with open(output_file_name , "w", newline="") as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            for row in reader:
                name = row[0]
                grade_mean = (float(grade) for grade in row [1:])
                avarage_list.append([name, mean(grade_mean)])
            avarage_list.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
            for item in avarage_list[:3]:
                writer.writerow([item[0], float(item[1])])


def calculate_three_worst(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    avarage_list = []
    with open(input_file_name) as infile:
        reader=csv.reader(infile)
        with open(output_file_name , "w", newline="") as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            for row in reader:
                name = row[0]
                grade_mean = (float(grade) for grade in row [1:])
                avarage_list.append([name, mean(grade_mean)])
            avarage_list = sorted(sorted(avarage_list, key = lambda x : x[0]), key = lambda x : x[1], reverse = True)
            avarage_list_worst = avarage_list[-3:]
            avarage_list_worst.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
            for item in avarage_list_worst:
                writer.writerow([float(item[1])])          


def calculate_average_of_averages(input_file_name, output_file_name):
    avarage_list = []
    with open(input_file_name) as infile:
        reader=csv.reader(infile)
        with open(output_file_name , "w", newline="") as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            for row in reader:
                name = row[0]
                grade_mean = (float(grade) for grade in row [1:])
                avarage_list.append([name, mean(grade_mean)])
            all_mean = [float(el[1]) for el in avarage_list]
            writer.writerow([mean(all_mean)])
```